# How to do a Join Query on a Mysql fetch in JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpql

I have a table Users

```
Id(key)  |  username | some other cols...n
```

and a table Tokens:

```
userID, Token (k)
```

userID in Tokens is defined as being the foreign key from users.id.

What i want to do is to be able to : Given a Tokens.token, get the col info from Users.

the mysql command in SQL is like such:

```
select a.* from users a left join tokens b on a.User_Id = b.userId and b.userId = 1;
```

(i dont know if the above is optimal...but it returns what i want)

How would i replicate that in JPQL?

The simple select fetch command i am familar with is: (other than using the built in one)

```
String qlString = "Select p from Tokens p WHERE p.token=:token";
        TypedQuery<Tokens> query = this.entityManager.createQuery(qlString,Tokens.class).setParameter("token", token);
```

Comment: You need something like `Select p form Tokens join p.user`, add your entitties for a better answer

Comment: @AVolpe assume my entities are mapped like above..

class Users has Int Id and class Tokens has int userID

Answer (score 0):

When you use JPA, you don't mind for table and columns, you use Entities and Relations, the query must be:

```
select u.info from User u join u.tokens t where t.token = :token
```

This assumes:

```
@Entity class User {
    @OneToMany List<Token> tokens;
    String info;
}

@Entity class Token {
    String token;
}
```

You start from `User`, then go with your attribute `tokens` to the `Token` entity, and filter for the `Token` attribute.

To get the list you use:

```
List<String> infos = entityManager.createQuery(YOUR_QUERY).list();
```